# Is it okay to use a Modal segue to leave a view that won't ever show up again?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, segue

I am working on an app that, when you first launch it, has a login screen that connects to a server. If you enter a valid username and password, this login screen goes away and you are taken to the main screen for this app.

The main screen gives you options of what to do, and it is assumed that you will not go back to the login screen again probably. Maybe 1% of people might log out of the app and go back to the login screen I guess.

Since I am not using a Navigation Controller to go from the login view to the main view, I have to use a modal segue, but it doesn't feel right to do so, as far as my knowledge of the theory behind modal segues. Am I crazy? Should I maybe just somehow use a Navigation Controller anyway?

I just feel this is not proper style, to use a modal segue to basically cover up the login screen, when it really isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a home screen (main view controller) that displays the login screen modally on app start. Once login is complete you can dismiss the login screen and your app is running as usual.

It's extremely bad practice to leave a view controller running when it's unlikely to be used again.

Comment: Thank you, this makes SUCH perfect sense, I don't know why I didn't think of it, it's clearly the logical solution! I knew doing it the other way was dumb.